# Fail to implement Cardano method. Cube root of a complex number

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, math, numba

In order to improve `np.roots` performance on cubic equation, I try to implement [Cardan(o) Method](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9thode_de_Cardan#Formules_de_Cardan) :

```
def cardan(a,b,c,d):
    #"resolve P=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0" 
    #"x=z-b/a/3=z-z0 => P=z^3+pz+q"
    z0=b/3/a
    a2,b2 = a*a,b*b    
    p=-b2/3/a2 +c/a
    q=(b/27*(2*b2/a2-9*c/a)+d)/a
    D=-4*p*p*p-27*q*q+0j
    r=sqrt(-D/27)
    J=-0.5+0.86602540378443871j # exp(2i*pi/3)
    u=((-q+r)/2)**(1/3)
    v=((-q-r)/2)**(1/3)
    return u+v-z0,u*J+v/J-z0,u/J+v*J-z0
```

It works well when roots are real:

```
In [2]: P=poly1d([1,2,3],True)
In [3]: roots(P)
Out[3]: array([ 3.,  2.,  1.])
In [4]: cardan(*P)
Out[4]: ((3+0j), (1+0j), (2+1.110e-16j))
```

But fails in the complex case :

```
In [8]: P=poly1d([1,-1j,1j],True)
In [9]: P
Out[9]: poly1d([ 1., -1.,  1., -1.])
In [10]: roots(P)
Out[10]: array([  1.0000e+00+0.j,   7.771e-16+1.j,   7.771e-16-1.j])
In [11]: cardan(*P)
Out[11]: ((1.366+0.211j),(5.551e-17+0.577j),(-0.366-0.788j))
```

I guess that the problem is the evaluation of `u` and `v` by cube roots .
[Theory](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9thode_de_Cardan#Formules_de_Cardan) say `uv=-p/3`, but here `uv=pJ/3`: `(u,v)` is not a good pair of roots.

What is the best way to obtain a correct pair in all cases ?

**EDIT**

After @Sally post, I can precise the problem. The good pair is not  always `(u,v)`, it can be  `(u,vJ)` or `(uJ,v)`. So the question could be :

- is there a straightforward method to catch the good pair ?

And ultimate : for the moment, by compiling this code with `Numba`, it's 20x faster than `np.roots` .

- is there a better algorithm to compute the three roots of a cubic equation ?

Comment: Are you looking for something like De Moivre's Theorem?

Comment: not really. `sin` and `cos` are time consuming. I look after a fast way to know what in `(v, Jv, J²v)` must be associated to `u` to find the good roots.

Comment: They shouldn't be unless you use them a *lot*: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3836083/5277935

Comment: Do you use Python 2 or 3? Because in Python 2, "1/3" is 0.

Comment: @cfh : Python 3, elsewhere nothing will work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You correctly identified the problem: there are three possible values of cubic root in a complex plane, resulting in 9 possible pairs of `((-q+r)/2)**(1/3)` and `((-q-r)/2)**(1/3)`. Of these 9, only 3 pairs lead to the correct roots: namely, those for which u*v = -p/3. An easy fix is to replace the formula for `v` with `v=-p/(3*u)`. This is probably also a speed-up: division should be faster than taking cubic root.

However `u` might be equal or close to zero, in which case the division becomes suspect. Indeed, already in your first example it makes the precision slightly worse. Here is a numerically robust approach: insert these two lines before the return statement.

```
choices = [abs(u*v*J**k+p/3) for k in range(3)]
v = v*J**choices.index(min(choices))
```

This loops over the three candidates for v, picking whichever minimizes the absolute value of `u*v+p/3`. Perhaps one can slightly improve the performance here by storing the three candidates so that the winner does not have to be recomputed.

Comment: Thank's for this confirmation  and suggestions. I guess there is a more direct and symmetric approach, but I don't see it at the moment.  I edit my post in this goal.

Comment: Final version here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35795663/fastest-way-to-find-the-smallest-positive-real-root-of-quartic-polynomial-4-degr/35829660#35829660 . I prefer avoid the division by `u` to limit rounding issues, but the precision is not very good.

Answer (score 2):

Since the sign of `r` as one of the square roots is free (resp. the role of `u` and `v` is interchangeable in `u+v` and of `u^3,v^3` as roots of a quadratic polynomial) set

```
u3 = (abs(q+r)>abs(q-r))? -(q+r) : -(q-r)

u = u3**(1/3)
v = -p/(3*u)
```

This makes sure that the divisor is always as large as possible, reducing the error in the quotient and minimizing the number of cases where division by (near) zero might become an issue.

Comment: Thanks. It will nevertheless fails on `q=p=0`, which is not an rare case.

Comment: Naturally, you have to check,catch and treat these special cases beforehand. People have tried robust implementations of Cardano, as I read somewhere, it gets rather lengthy. --`p==0 => z=(-q)**(1/3)*J^k`, `q==0 => z = 0, +-(-p)**(1/2)` etc.